# xts - how to subset on each day of the week

Tags: r, xts

I understand similar questions have been answered. My problem is I have a time series data for 2033 days on 15 minutes interval. I would like to plot the series for each day (Mon-Sun). For instance how an average Monday looks like.

I tried to subset by using `.indexwday`, but the series for the day starts at 13:00.

I am kind of novice, so please let me know if I need to provide additional details.

Sample data (xts)

- 2008-01-01 00:00:00   16
- 2008-01-01 00:15:00   56
- 2008-01-01 00:30:00  136
- 2008-01-01 00:45:00  170
- 2008-01-01 01:00:00  132

....

- 2013-07-25 22:30:00   95
- 2013-07-25 22:45:00   82
- 2013-07-25 23:00:00   66
- 2013-07-25 23:15:00   65
- 2013-07-25 23:30:00   66
- 2013-07-25 23:45:00   46

The plot below might make more sense what I want (This is the average of all Mondays)

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your data if it's not sensitive to share? If it happens to be, then please provide one that is similar in dimension and structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another solution, which does not depend on packages other than xts and zoo.

```
# example data
ix <- seq(as.POSIXct("2008-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2013-07-26"), by="15 min")
set.seed(21)
x <- xts(sample(200, length(ix), TRUE), ix)

# aggregate by 15-minute observations for each weekday
a <- lapply(split.default(x, format(index(x), "%A")),         # split by weekday
  function(x) aggregate(x, format(index(x), "%H:%M"), mean))  # aggregate by 15-min
# merge aggregated data into one zoo object, ordering columns
z <- do.call(merge, a)[,c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")]
# convert index to POSIXct to make plotting easier
index(z) <- as.POSIXct(index(z), format="%H:%M")
# plot
plot(z, type="l", nc=1, ylim=range(z), main="Average daily volume", las=1)
```

Setting `ylim` forces each plot to have the same y-axis range. Otherwise they would depend on each individual series, which may make them difficult to compare if the values vary greatly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    #Get necessary packages
install.packages("lubridate")
install.packages("magrittr")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("scales")

#Import packages
library(lubridate,warn=F)
library(dplyr,warn=F)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2,warn=F)
library(scales, warn=F)

#Getting the data
tstart = as.POSIXct('2008-01-01 00:00:00')
tend = as.POSIXct('2013-07-25 23:45:00')
ttimes <- seq(from = tstart,to=tend,by='15 mins')
tvals <- sample(seq(1,200),length(ttimes),T)
tsdata <- data.frame(Dates=ttimes,Vals=tvals)
tsdata <- tsdata %>% mutate(DayofWeek = wday(Dates,label=T), Hours = as.POSIXct(strftime(Dates,format="%H:%M:%S"),format="%H:%M:%S"))

#Pick a day at a time. I am using Mondays for this example.
tsdata_monday <- tsdata %>% filter(DayofWeek=='Mon') %>% group_by(Hours) %>% summarise(meanVals=mean(Vals)) %>% as.data.frame()

#Plotting the graph of mean values versus times for Monday:
ggplot(tsdata_monday) + aes(x=Hours,y=meanVals) + geom_line() + scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("4 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image: Monday plot]

```
#If you want you can go ahead and plot all the days. But please keep in mind
#that this does not look good at all. Too many plots for the plot window to
#Display nicely.
alltsdata <- tsdata %>% group_by(DayofWeek, Hours) %>% summarise(MeanVals=mean(Vals)) %>% as.data.frame()

ggplot(alltsdata) + aes(x=Hours,y=MeanVals) + geom_line() + scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("4 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M")) + facet_grid(.~DayofWeek)
```

[image: Full plot]

I recommend you plot one day at a time or use a `for loop` or one of the `apply` function variations to get the plots.

Also when filtering by day of the week, please keep in mind that the days are shortened as follows:

```
unique(tsdata$DayofWeek)
[1] Tues  Wed   Thurs Fri   Sat   Sun   Mon
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`apply.daily` does exactly what you want.( assumming your data is called `d.xts` and a xts-object)

```
apply.daily(d.xts,sum)
```

another solution would be using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(d.xts,as.Date(index(d.xts)),sum)
```

Note that the answers are slightly different: `apply.daily` starts from `start(d.xts) to end(d.xts)` whereas `aggregate` goes by day from midnight to midnight.